wow.js happens on page load and not on scroll in Vue2
I use wow.js in Vue2, and the animation will be triggered immediately after the page is loaded, rather than when the element is scrolled to the viewport
<div class="wow fadeInLeftBig animated" data-wow-delay="0.5s">
            <div class="service_photo">
                <img src="img_url" alt=""/>
            </div>
</div>

I hope the code can run normally, just scroll the element to the viewport and then trigger the animation
